# unable to pass arguments in python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

This is my sample `query.py`

```
class Query:
     XYZ = """ select * from table where date_format(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') = '{date}' """
```

In my `main.py`

```
current_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

def example():
    df = pd.read_sql(Query.XYZ.format(date=current_date), self.db)
    print(df)
```

I'm using SQLAlchemy.

But I'm ending up with this error
`ValueError: unsupported format character 'Y' (0x59) at index 309`. I read others solution on this, but didn't understand quite well.

Comment: I believe you need to use `%%` where the `%` is not intended to be interpreted as a string formatter by Python. So, `.. date_format(created_at, '%%Y-%%m-%%d') ...` may work.

Comment: Oh good to know! Thanks!